# DateTime data correction in pandas based on previous row

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows similar to the follows:

```
    Time                    Fix
0   2020-10-30 00:12:00     UMEKO
0   2020-10-30 00:26:00     PASOV
0   2020-10-30 00:30:00     KUPMA
1   2020-10-30 23:32:00     RASKI
1   2020-10-30 23:52:00     VAXIM
1   2020-10-30 00:21:00     BORER
2   2020-10-30 23:56:00     RAGMA
2   2020-10-30 00:05:00     SODEB
2   2020-10-30 00:08:00     VUSET
```

I need to correct the data, in order to show the correct Date based on the time entry. So the updated dataframe shall be like following:

```
    Time                    Fix
0   2020-10-30 00:12:00     UMEKO
0   2020-10-30 00:26:00     PASOV
0   2020-10-30 00:30:00     KUPMA
1   2020-10-30 23:32:00     RASKI
1   2020-10-30 23:52:00     VAXIM
1   2020-10-31 00:21:00     BORER
2   2020-10-30 23:56:00     RAGMA
2   2020-10-31 00:05:00     SODEB
2   2020-10-31 00:08:00     VUSET
```

Changes Done:

```
1   2020-10-30 00:21:00     BORER
```

to

```
1   2020-10-31 00:21:00     BORER
```

,

```
2   2020-10-30 00:05:00     SODEB
```

to

```
2   2020-10-31 00:05:00     SODEB
```

,

```
2   2020-10-30 00:08:00     VUSET
```

to

```
2   2020-10-31 00:08:00     VUSET
```

The changes are done by comparing to the previous cell in the group and to see if it is greater than 23:59:59 then it shall be the next day

Comment: What are groups? Do you think unique values in `Fix` are groups? Or something else?

Comment: Wh yis changed `2020-10-31 00:08:00` if previous values is `2020-10-31 00:05:00`, so differnce is not  greater than 23:59:59 ?

Comment: The groups are the rows with same index values. The first row of that group was less than 23:59:59 and then the rows after it were greater than 23:59:59 so they shall be on next date

Comment: ok, so use `mask = df['Time'].sub(df.groupby(level=0)['Time'].shift()).dt.total_seconds() < 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need difference only by previous values use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

#test shifted values per groups if total second is negative
mask = df['Time'].sub(df.groupby(level=0)['Time'].shift()).dt.total_seconds() < 0

#repeat values after first True
mask1 = mask.groupby(level=0).cummax()
#add 1 day by second mask
df['Time'] = df['Time'].mask(mask1, df['Time'] + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd'))
print (df)
                 Time    Fix
0 2020-10-30 00:12:00  UMEKO
0 2020-10-30 00:26:00  PASOV
0 2020-10-30 00:30:00  KUPMA
1 2020-10-30 23:32:00  RASKI
1 2020-10-30 23:52:00  VAXIM
1 2020-10-31 00:21:00  BORER
2 2020-10-30 23:56:00  RAGMA
2 2020-10-31 00:05:00  SODEB
2 2020-10-31 00:08:00  VUSET
```

Comment: The last row of 2 shall also have the date changed to 2020-10-31 . However with this way it is the same.

Comment: All rows after the first detected in the group shall be changed.

Comment: @AliSultan - I got it.

Comment: @AliSultan - Can you test now?